# how to use trigger in mysql to update a column's value from particular date to till date only for a unique customer id

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I'm Working on A **c# form Application** with **mysql Database**.

below Is design of ,table i'm using to save my data for 
customer with following columns..

id : auto-increment id for identify each row and getting balance for customer with max id of cid

cid : customer's ID

billno  : invoice number 
deposit : the amount being deposit against that bill 
billtotal : the total amount of bill...

**balance :  previous balance + current billtotal - current billdeposit**

I'm calculating balance with my form application 
and everything works fine

Now the problem is with deleting a bill or updating a bill

**suppose in bill no. 9  i have entered 100 instead of 1000**
Now i wants to change that value

**

> if I'll change that then  all my calculations of balance column  from
>   that row to last row will be  wrong.

**

what will best way to Do So....

i'm thinking of a trigger after update for this but i don't know how 
to create a trigger to perform these calculation only for current row to last row and only for that customers cid

[image: Image of my Table design]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** You can calculate the values at runtime and display instead of storing them on the database.

forexample : you will only store the `billdiposit` amount in the database but while displaying the overall report you calculate the balance as below and display:

```
balance = previousbalance+deposit
```

**Solution 2:** You need to update the relavent columns when you update/modify the deposit column.

forexample: if you are modifying the deposit column :

```
update financetable
set deposit=100 where id=1 and cid=2;
```

after executing the above command, update the relavent columns from same table or table which are related to `deposit` column

example : update current balance asbelow:

```
update financetable
set balance = previousbalance+deposit where id=1 and cid=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not cache the balance.

```
SELECT SUM(billtotal)-SUM(deposit) FROM table WHERE cid = x
```

This is a pretty simple query, which should operate fine on every database even with lots of rows. Put an index on the `cid` column and you are good to go without saving the balance and the problems which arise out of this caching column.